# Plain text agenda formatting recognition by Siri

Tags: calendar, siri

I will be hosting a small conference and want to send an email to participants containing a full agenda as plain text or in form of a short pdf as an attachment.
I wanted to format it that way that Siri would recognize every individual event on the list and suggest adding it to the calendar.
Unfortunately, I cannot find any description for formatting.
Usually, I do it in that way:

> Start date/time - End date/time  | Event 1 Title | Event 1 Speaker | Event 1 Location | Event 1 Description
> Start date/time - End date/time  | Event 2 Title | Event 2 Speaker | Event 2 Location | Event 2 Description

but in that case, Siri is only recognizing starting date and leaves the rest empty (same case for pdf).

Does anybody know where can I find text formatting schemas for Siri to fully recognize events and allow adding them to the calendar?

Answer (score -1):

I do not really understand why Siri should be involved?

First create a new calendar (click on the “File” menu, select “New Calendar” and then “iCloud”). You can name it to whatever you feel like and share it by clicking share icon to the right of the calendar’s name. You can even make it a public calendar, which means anyone can subscribe to a read-only version of your calendar.

Second define all events in this calendar. (For future changes make sure to have syncing of calendars to iCloud activated).

In the edit screen of the calendar you can directly add people with whom you want to share it.

Apple provides more info [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/calendar/icl1016/11.0/mac/11.0).